# Android Dynamic Imageview with Rotate, Scale in Dynamic Location

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation

I want to add dynamic imageview in Relative layout and this imageview move/ scale / Rotate in any position on OnTouch Event

Code Add Dynamic Imageview in Relative layout:

```
        private void Mount_Image(String btn_id ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ImageView my_ballon = new ImageView(this);

            my_ballon.setTag(btn_id);
            my_ballon.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            my_ballon.setLayoutParams(lp);


            my_ballon.setImageResource(R.drawable.mustache_1);

            rel_image.addView(my_ballon);
           // Add_Drag_hadler(btn_id);

            my_ballon.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }
```

Add Imageview in rel_image(Relative layout).

Here is code of ontouch event:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // handle touch events here
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;


            final float x = event.getX();
            final float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                        lastEvent = null;

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                    }
                    lastEvent = new float[4];
                    lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                    lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                    lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                    lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                    d = rotation(event);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    lastEvent = null;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if (!rotate_enabled) {

                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        view.requestLayout();
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                        float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                        matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                        view.invalidate();
                    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

                        }

                    }
                    }
                    else {

                        if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                            view.requestLayout();

                            newRot = rotation(event);
                            float r = newRot - d;
                            float[] values = new float[9];
                            matrix.getValues(values);
                            float tx = values[2];
                            float ty = values[5];
                            float sx = values[0];


                            float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                            float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                           // matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                            animate(r, tx + xc, 0,view);
                          //  lastEvent=null;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;
        }



     /**
         * Determine the space between the first two fingers
         */
        private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }

        /**
         * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
         */
        private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
            float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
            point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }

        private void animate(double fromDegrees, double toDegrees, long durationMillis,ImageView wheel) {
            final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float)fromDegrees, (float)toDegrees,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);


            rotate.setDuration(durationMillis);
            rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
            rotate.setFillAfter(true);
            wheel.startAnimation(rotate);


            }


        /**
         * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
         *
         * @param event
         * @return Degrees
         */
        private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
            double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
            double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
            double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
            return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
        }
```

Imageview Drag and scaling working properly but when i try to rotate image this rotate around center of background... i need imageview rotate around self
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

change these lines:

`Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF` to `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT`

```
final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float)fromDegrees, (float)toDegrees,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);
```

to

```
final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float)fromDegrees, (float)toDegrees,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                    0.5f);
```

Comment: try this constructor for rotate animation, and here piviteX, and pivoteY are which you want to maintain the center position. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html#RotateAnimation%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29

Comment: <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:startOffset="0"/> i tried this also ... but no luck

Comment: if you want to rotate the image with dynamic center with your touch positions, you have to create the rotate object dynamically, and update the pivoteX and pivoteY dynamically.

Comment: float xc = (view.getPivotX() / 2) * sx; float yc = (view.getPivotY() / 2) * sx;   No Luck :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the rotation pivot. Try this:

```
matrix.postTranslate(-mid.x, -mid.y);
matrix.postRotate(r);
matrix.postTranslate(mid.x, mid.y);
```